# How do you find the conditional variance of $X$ when you are only told that $X$ is greater than 8?

Tags: probability

The PDF is $0.5 e^{-|x-2|} $

I calculated $E(X)$ to be $2$, and $E(X^2)=6$.
Now I need help finding $var(X | X > 8)$

*A lot of this question was removed as it was incorrect information*

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Could you please state what you know about $X$ so that we can help? Are you provided values and corresponding probabilities? How did you calculate that $\mathbb{E}[X] = 2$ for example?

Comment: @Clarinetist I updated the question to include more information.
I am mostly just confused as to whether $var(X|X>c) = (E(X^2)+c^2) + (E(X)+c)^2$

Comment: The title and body information are inconsistent. Is it $8$ or $9$?

Comment: @Zhanxiong sorry, 8, thanks for catching that

Comment: @Shawn There are a few other typos, please take more time to fully correct them. No rush. Also, you don't need to put what edits you made in the question, they can be found in the edit history.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thank you, this is my first time on here (as you can tell), I think I've fixed everything now.

Comment: What kind of random variable is $X$?  Is it exponential?

Comment: Now the problem is that some of your statement is invalid, for example: why $E[X | X > 8] = 8 + E[X]$, are you dealing with a specific type of random variable $X$?

Comment: @Zhanxiong: That's why I guessed exponential, but the other information is currently not quite consistent with that guess.

Comment: Please provide the pdf.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I have added the PDF

Comment: @BrianTung It does not say in the question that it is exponential, but based on the PDF I assume it is, sorry I'm new to probability

Comment: @Zhanxiong I thought that $E[X|X>c]=c+E[X]$ holds true for all random variables, but based on your response, I guess that is incorrect...

Comment: Your thought is quite obviously incorrect --- as we are at a math forum, we should rely on the logic/proof instead of any plausible thoughts/guesses. To say it doesn't mean you can't make any guess, the essential thing is after you made the guess, you **MUST** be able to justify it by logical proofs. When you cannot, restrain yourself to state it.

Comment: It only holds for the *few* distribution families with the memoryless property. That pdf is does not belong to any such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The pdf is $0.5\mathrm e^{-\lvert x-2\rvert}$.

The support for that should be $(-\infty{..}\infty)$.

That pdf does not display the memoryless property, since clearly:  $$\mathsf P(X>8+x\mid X>8)\neq \mathsf P(X>x)$$

So we cannot say: $\mathsf E(X\mid X>8)=8+\mathsf E(X)$

You need to evaluate $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X>8) &= \int_8^\infty 0.5 \exp(-\lvert x-2\rvert)~\mathrm d x\\[1ex]\mathsf E(X\mid X>8) &= \mathsf P(X>8)^{-1}\int_8^\infty 0.5 x\exp(-\lvert x-2\rvert)~\mathrm d x\\[1ex] \mathsf E(X^2\mid X>8) &= \mathsf P(X>8)^{-1}\int_8^\infty 0.5 x^2\exp(-\lvert x-2\rvert)~\mathrm d x\\[2ex] \mathsf{Var}(X\mid X>8)&= \mathsf E(X^2\mid X>8)-(\mathsf E(X\mid X>8))^2\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help with that!
Although now, how do I find $E(X | X > 8)$ and $E(X^2 | X > 8)$

Comment: The same way you found $\mathsf E(X)$ and $\mathsf E(X^2)$ ...

Comment: @Graham Kemp: the memoryless property can be used with a simple trick (see my latest answer)

Comment: Where did the $P(X>8)^{-1}$ come from? Why do we multiply the integral by that?

Comment: I'd say that's more exploiting a change of variable to give a well known integral., but yes. @tommik

Comment: Where would we get that value from? When we calculate $E(X^2|X > 8)$ and $E(X|X>8)$, we will need $P(X>8)^{-1}$

Comment: The normalisation coefficient is from the definition of conditioning over an event.

Answer (score 1):

The given fact that $\mathbb{E}[X|X>8]=8+\mathbb{E}[X]$ indicate that the rv X owns the "lack of memory property" so  $\mathbb{V}[X|X>8]= \mathbb{V}[X]=6-2^2=2$

Comment: It might be exponential with rate $1$ and shifted up by $1$ (that would account for the present information in the OP), but I'm not sure that can be ascertained with what we know now.

Comment: $E(X|X > 8) = 8 + E(X)$ was not a given fact in the question, its just a fact that I thought was true, but based on the responses here, I guess isn't. I have added the pdf to the question. Thanks :)